# How do reality and online TV shows prevent leaks regarding winner names?

Tags: reality-tv

Big Online Reality TV Shows are able to keep the winner names a secret even after the shooting is finished. Even after searching on the Internet one is not able to find them. How do they keep such things confidential when there are huge audiences present?

Comment: "Big Online Reality TV Shows" - like which ones? Most reality TV shows I know of (Big Brother, Love Island...) are broadcast live.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Survivor may be one example. I seem to remember many years back when they did have a leak. Naval guy out of Seattle area or something.

Comment: I was talking in general a recent example would be Comicstaan which is Amazon Prime India's Exclusive show and uploads an episode every Friday. It ended today.

Comment: @F1Krazy I am not talking about live ones but the ones which are pre-recorded

Comment: FWIW, my wife and I were on a game show, and we won some money. We had to sign a contract that said (1) we would get our money when the show aired in a few months, and (2) if we told anybody we won or posted our win on Twitter or something, we would _not_ get the money.

Comment: Whilst not a game show, I went to a live recording of the comedy sci-fi Red Dwarf. We didn't have to sign anything, but beforehand the main writer and co-creator basically asked the audience nicely not to spoil anything online, and I believe it worked - certainly didn't encounter anything for that episode, or any others.

Comment: @BrettFromLA I think you should make your experience as an answer

Comment: @Vishwa I thought about it, but the OP is asking about "reality TV" shows. A game show is technically "reality", but it's very different than _Survivor_ or _The Bachelorette_.

Comment: @BrettFromLA yes exactly I was also wondering why I'm getting all my answers as game shows. I am more concerned with shows where there is competition for a whole season rather than new people in every few episodes

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62443/how-do-they-keep-the-identity-of-the-winner-secret

Answer (score 6):

I had a friend who was on a baking competition show. He was required to sign a [non-disclosure agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement) saying that he would not reveal the winners or losers of the show until the episode had aired. There was some penalty if he did reveal anything, though I don't recall what it was. Surely if he had won (he didn't) they would have revoked his winnings.

On the up side, the day it aired, he baked several of the things he made on the show and we ate them while we watched the competition!

Comment: I have a friend who was on a quiz show, in addition to having to sign an NDA; if they won the episode/money this would not be paid out until the episode had aired.  So no rocking up in a brand new Mercedes saying he couldn't tell us if he'd won.